# Upstream timed out error when deploying Docker Nginx FastAPI application on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, fastapi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to deploy simple FastAPI app with Docker and Nginx proxy on Google Cloud using simple ssh-terminal window.

My nginx.conf:

```
access_log                  /var/log/nginx/app.log;
error_log                   /var/log/nginx/app.log;

proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
proxy_set_header Proxy "";

upstream app_server {
  server example.com:8000;
}

server {
  server_name               example.com;
  listen                    80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen                  443 ssl;
  server_name             example.com;
  ssl_certificate         /root/ssl/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /root/ssl/key.pem;
  location / {
    proxy_pass "http://app_server";
  }
}
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./ssl/cert1.pem:/root/ssl/cert.pem
      - ./ssl/privkey1.pem:/root/ssl/key.pem
      - ./ssl/dhparam.pem:/etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy

  web:
    environment: [.env]
    build: ./project
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: gunicorn main:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
      - back

networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    external:
      name: reverse-proxy
  back:
      driver: bridge
```

After run `docker-compose up` command and going to *example.com* address, I get error:

> *3 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream...

Also, I have opened ports with Google Cloud Firewall service (checked with *netstat* command) and configured my VM's instance with network parameters from [this article](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-reverse-proxy-docker).

I don't understand why I receive **504 Gateway Time-out** cause my service work with the similar configuration on a simple VPS hosting, and also it works from the inside Google Cloud VM's ssh-terminal when using *curl* and check *localhost* instead *example.com* domain. I want to know how to run my service on Google Cloud VM using only docker-compose util for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nginx config file, try to mention the web container name:

```
upstream app_server {
  server web:8000;
}
```